# ¿Como trabajo con fechas en python?

Tags: python, tkinter, date

Hola buenas mi duda es como puedo ofrecer un control al usuario para que introduzca una fecha en PYTHON que no sea un simple `Entry` con texto en gris... en plan `"Ejemplo: 27/10/2014"` o `"dd/mm/yyyy"`. Igual existe algo parecido a un calendario o otro elemento que ayude al usuario a introducir una fecha.

Gracias, saludos.

Estoy trabajando con la librería TKINTER.

Comment: Entiendo que estás usando alguna biblioteca para crear GUIs (interfaces gráficas de usuario), ¿no? ¿Cuál usas?

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando la libreria TKINTER

Comment: Tkinter no tiene _widget_ de calendario, pero [aqui](http://effbot.org/zone/wcklib-calendar.htm) hay una implementación (no la he probado, no sé si funcionará en python3.